# Unable to scroll vertical or horizantal in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, webview

1. i tried different android versions like 1.1.0 & 1.5.0
2. i tried different machines still same problem
3. i tried with empty activity and blank activity still same problem
4. i tried web view, relative layout, frame layout, text view, scroll view etc
5. all times its freeze i tried it build the app and install in blue stack empty coding also nothing scrolling just its freeze but other than that everything is OK, means page loading and image loading.

please somebody help me am hanged last one week.

Below is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.hanumaiahthangirala.runningmovies.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    </WebView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest code here

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Main Activity code.

```
package com.example.hanumaiahthangirala.runningmovies;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://runningmovies.in/");
    }
}
```

Comment: show your code please.

Comment: edit your question and add your code

Comment: Fix your network connection may help

Comment: @hanomaiaht You can notify people like that. Also, use the `{}` button in the editor to properly format code. As it is, your line breaks are ridiculous.

Comment: The app itself doesn't scroll? Or Android Studio freezes?

Comment: The app itself freeze after opened in avd device or installed in bluestacks. able to open the mentioned URL and do the activities as normal on same window means this URL is for search form. we are getting the output of the results but not able to scroll the window horizantal or vertical

Comment: i tried to add different websites also like if i put http://www.stackoverflow.com/ also same issue not able to scroll horizontal or vertical but if i press any link same window it will open and same freeze for that window also

Comment: Can anyone help on the solution am strucked